# echo not echoing the value correctly - BASH Linux without double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, variables, echo, double-quotes

Can someone please point out what shenzie I could have done here?? **PS**: Restarting a new shell/session doesn't recreate this issue.

```
[trinley@linuxserversb12 2]$ echo $gradle_HOME
/home/gradle/gradle- .6
[trinley@linuxserversb12 2]$ echo "$gradle_HOME"
/home/gradle/gradle-1.6

[trinley@linuxserversb12 2]$ echo $gradle_HOME; cd $_
/home/gradle/gradle- .6
-bash: cd: .6: No such file or directory

[trinley@linuxserversb12 2]$ echo "$gradle_HOME"; cd $_
/home/gradle/gradle-1.6
-bash: cd: /home/gradle/gradle-: No such file or directory

[trinley@linuxserversb12 2]$ echo "$gradle_HOME"; cd "$_"
/home/gradle/gradle-1.6

[trinley@linuxserversb12 gradle-1.6]$ pwd
/home/gradle/gradle-1.6

[trinley@linuxserversb12 gradle-1.6]$ echo $gradle_HOME; cd "$_"
/home/gradle/gradle- .6
-bash: cd: .6: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm basically looking for what settings could have impacted this behavior. Doing ^J stty sane ^J on $ prompt, doesn't bring the default shell setting back i.e. still getting this issue in this shell/session.

Comment: Try `echo "$gradle_HOME" | xxd`.

Comment: You should just avoid `$_`.

Comment: You should usually expect variables without double quotes to not interpolate to what you set them to. In other words, always use double quotes unless you know exactly why not.

Comment: @konsolebox Yes, I know that. But, I'm trying to find is - what triggered this behavior.

Comment: @tripleee sure, as I mentioned in my post, even without using double quotes, it's working fine in a new windows/shell/session. I'm trying to find, what's making "echo" to ignore "1" from gradle-1.6 when quotes are not used in the current window (where Im seeing this behavior).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `IFS` variable was set to `1`or something that includes it. This causes word splitting to your variables that includes `1` as a separator.

Set it back with `IFS=$' \t\n'`.

Comment: @ooga It's too volatile and has too many functions. At least that's how I find it.

Comment: @konsolebox It's not set to to 1. Thanks for the hint though. I guess it helped resolving the issue.

Comment: I can accept as answer as you mentioned IFS being set to something which includes 1. Now, that raises a ?, what if I want to set IFS as newline char

Comment: For bash it's `IFS=$'\n'`. And the original or normal IFS is `$' \t\n'`. Equivalent to `$'\n'` is also `$'\012'` (oct) and `$'\x0a'` (hex).

Answer (score 0):

Setting IFS=" " solved the issue. It was not set to 1 or anything other than a newline char '\012'

IFS was set to newline character i.e.

```
[trinley@linuxserversb12 gradle-1.6]$ echo $IFS - "'$IFS'"
    - '\012'
```

Setting is back to a single space, solved the issue.

```
export IFS=" "
$ echo $GRADLE_HOME; cd $_; echo; pwd
/home/gradle/gradle-1.6

/home/gradle/gradle-1.6
$
```

Comment: Your `IFS` was set to `$'\\012'` (literal `\012`) not `$'\012'`.